# How can I do a simple search form/function in yii2?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2

I want to do a search using a form which will search name field, brand field and category field.

1. Should I be using post or get for this situation?
2. How/where should I be creating my query search model, model or controller?

Any code snippets would be great.

I have the following in my view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'home-search','method' => 'get', 'action' => Url::to(['productitem/search'])]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($productitem, 'name')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'What are you looking for?'))->label(false) ?>

    <?= $form->field($productitem, 'brand_id')->dropDownList(

        ArrayHelper::map(ProductBrand::find()->all(),'id','name'),
        ['prompt'=>'Select Brand']

    )->label(false) ?>

    <?= $form->field($productitem, 'category_id')->dropDownList(

        ArrayHelper::map(ProductCategory::find()->all(),'id','name'),
        ['prompt'=>'Select Department']

    )->label(false) ?>

    <div class="form-group search-button">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="login-button">Search <i class="fa fa-lg fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></button>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your questions:

1. I would use get just for the convenience of pressing the "back" button. You are not changing the database at all so a GET should provide enough security / convenience
2. search model should be in the [Model]Search. Yii2 has specialized search models on top of the normal models why not keep them there? That is exactly what they are there for.

No code snippets SO helps you with your code, does not usually writes it for you. But then again somebody will probably come and spoon feed you code anyway so you will not learn anything so enjoy.